# Running a while loop in a separate thread to check for background tasks

Tags: python, multithreading

Would this be a bad practice, or is there another better way to do such a thing? What I have currently is a program that has a CLI menu system to take user input and based off that input will set up a query the database for data, and do analysis on it.

What I'd like to do, however, is set up that query with a datetime for it to start, then add it to a queue. Optimally, I would put this on the event loop for my menu system, but the menu system pauses while waiting for user input (either through the built in python `input` function or through the curses `window.getkey` function). In addition, I want to still be able to use the menu while data is being analysed

So what I'm doing is using two threads, one to check if there's any objects in the queue with a datetime of less than `datetime.now()`, remove it from the queue, do the analysis, and then continue checking the queue.

```
class AnalysisQueue(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, initial_queue):
        super(AnalysisQueue, self).__init__()
        self.alive = True
        self.queue = initial_queue

    def run(self):
        while self.alive: #loop can be terminated externally
            for i,object in enumerate(self.queue):
                if datetime.now() > object.analysis_start:
                    analyse_data(self.queue.pop(i)) #defined elsewhere


class Menu(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Menu, self).__init__()
        self.date_menu = MultipleChoiceMenu([
            {'description': "Test1"},
            {'description': "Test2"},
            {'description': "Test3"},
        ]) #Menu class that handles display and I/O for the menu

    def run(self):
        self.date_menu.input() #initializes the menu display and waits for input

analysis_thread = AnalysisQueue()
menu_thread = Menu()

analysis_thread.start()
menu_thread.start()
menu_thread.join() #waits for the menu thread to finish (menu is exited)
analysis_thread.alive = False 
#Now that menu has been exited, terminate program.
#whether or not the queue has entries in it at this point is not a concern
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach, or rather, is there a better way to do it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite an open-ended question, more like code review, but here's my feedback:

- You could use a [priority queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue) instead of going through the whole list looking for timestamps. Then you would only need to look at the head of the queue.
- I'd change the `self.alive` from a `bool` to an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects). They are thread-safe.
- This looks like a regular work queue to me, which is often used to keep the GUI thread responsive. I don't understand the reason for your timestamps however - why not run tasks immediately?
- How do you communicate the result of the analysis back to the main thread?
- Your code for appending tasks to the queue is not included. If you are simply doing `analysis_thread.queue.append(task)` you will get into trouble - since your implementation is using a list. Lists are not thread-safe (maybe appends are atomic, but I'm not sure `pop` is), so you'll probably need some synchronization for that.
- Maybe you can try to separate the logic of the queueing and the worker thread.

In conclusion. I'd set up a worker, like you did, and a regular [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) for tasks. Maybe [this](http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/10/producer-consumer-problem-in-python/) is a good start?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it is kind of a code review isn't it? Thanks for the information, I didn't realize that about Events. The timestamps are necessary because the analysis uses data for a certain period before the analysis is run, so this way I can set a number of reports to run at once (e.g. run a report one hour from now, one day from now, etc.). I'll definitely look into using a priority queue, so thank you!